# Network protocol design to communicate with microcontroller

Tags: networking, client-server, microcontroller

I was assigned to continue an old project at work and now I am at the point of designing a network protocol.
Here's the situation:
There are several microcontrollers with a GSM module for internet access. Once a day or something, they connect to a central server for data exchange.

The problem is, I always sticked to a rather strict client-server model, but I have a strange feeling on this now. Maybe because the microcontrollers aren't just like other clients. They are inaccessible and have to work autonomously.

Are there any guidelines for things like this? Maybe it is bad style to use this model for mcs? I never worked with microcontrollers, I have no idea about this.

Thanks for input,
Wolle

Comment: What sort of data do you need to transfer from the micros to send to the central server? Also, what packet sizes roughly? Are the micros going to send out to the central server without being asked or will they be polled?

Comment: The micros are sending some sensor data, maybe we get to a maximum of 300-400 bytes (+TCP/IP packing). The larger transmission is a possible update of the software. The other point is exactly my question: Due to a RTC activating the micros once a day, they are only accessible at that time and have to open the connection. Therefore, client-server seems about right. I am just wondering about this because I found an old protocol going another way. But that doesn't have to say anything.

Comment: I don't know what client-server means I'm afraid, but if the server is available all the time and your microcontroller boards are capable of initiating a connection to the server then there is no reason at all why it shouldn't work that way. In fact, this is a better way to work because there isn't endless polling by the server for a tiny amount of data from the micro. In terms of the world of microcontrollers, there is certainly no bad practice in having the micro be the one that dictates when data should be sent out.